# Overlaying and cropping following image alignment

Tags: image-processing

Using the ImageAlign function and the surf algorithm I have aligned 2 images. In an attempt to overlay the new images I have used ColorCombine. From the resulting image I would like to crop the parts that align between both images. I am also not sure if ColorCombine is the right function for overlaying.

Example images below
[image]